# Function returning same value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have been trying to run the following Javascript function:
(also using jquery)

```
function checkBijeenkomst(bid){
var value = false;
var login_accid = window.localStorage.getItem("id");
$.getJSON("firstapp/restservices/inschrijvingen/bid/" + bid, function(data){
    if (data != undefined){
    var acc_id = data[0].aid;
        if (login_accid == acc_id){
            console.log("true value");
            value = true;
        }
    }
});
return value;}
```

which btw gets this array as input from the JSON path:

```
[{"iid":2,"bid":46,"aid":1}]
```

but the function always returns the first given value. Even if the console logs ("true value").. How do I solve this?
I am quite the newbie probably with this problem. But any advice is welcome.

Comment: The problem is that getJSON is async, but the moment you `return value` the json code didn't run yet.

Comment: @kblok yea I kinda figured but otherwise it permanently returns undefined which isn't really an option. So still trying to solve that.

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/

Comment: @DonovanM thanks. Am trying now to see how to rewrite the code c:

Comment: @manishkeer I think you could put that as answer

Comment: return promise instead.

refer - https://davidwalsh.name/promises

Comment: @manishkeer yes, I am trying to atm. Will tag u again if I succeeded.